# iOS: Tableview multiple selection - AccessoryCheckmark checking reusable cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm using a tableview with sections and multiple selection, but I have an issue with multiple rows being checked when one row is chosen...
I've seen a few other threads about this, but didn't really get a solution...

Here's my code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{    
    [employeeTable deselectRowAtIndexPath:[employeeTable indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:NO];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [employeeTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];    

    // get the letter in each section
    NSString *alphabet = [charIndex objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    // get the names beginning with the letter
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", alphabet];    

    NSArray *names = [listOfNames filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];    

    NSString *name = [names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    for(int i = 0; i < [employeeConnection.employees count]; i++)
    {
        Employee *aEmployee = [employeeConnection.employees objectAtIndex:i];

        NSString *firstName = aEmployee.firstName;
        NSString *lastName = aEmployee.lastName;
        NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];

        if([fullName isEqualToString:name])
        { 
            NSLog(@"Name: %@", name);

            if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {

                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

                // Reflect selection in data model
                [chosenEmployees addObject:aEmployee.employeeID];
                [chosenEmployeesNames addObject:name];

            } else if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {

                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

                // Reflect deselection in data model
                [chosenEmployees removeObject:aEmployee.employeeID];
                [chosenEmployeesNames removeObject:name];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update: Added cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }

    // Get the letter in the current section
    NSString *alphabet = [charIndex objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];

    // Get the names beginning with the letter
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", alphabet];
    NSArray *names = [listOfNames filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    if([names count] > 0)
    {
        // Extract the name
        cell.textLabel.text = [names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Is it just the reused cells that are being checked when you don't want them? As in when you scroll around?

Comment: I have around 14 rows divided in sections... When I select e.g the first row, another row further down in another section is also selected... (Sections - A: 1(I check this row) row, C: 1 row, D: 1, H: 2, J: 2, K: 1(this is checked as well) M: 2, P: 1, S:1, T:2)...

Comment: You're going to have to post your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` code, or whatever method you are setting up the cells for display in.

Comment: I've added it in the questions....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would suggest storing an `NSMutableSet` of either the checked ManagedObject (when using CoreData) or simply the checked IndexPaths. In -cellForRowAtIndexPath: you can then check if the cell is supposed to be checked.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *const identifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor;
    }

    if ([self.checkedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *const cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [table deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    if ([self.checkedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath]) {
        [self.checkedIndexPaths removeObject:indexPath];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    else {
        [self.checkedIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help. But remember that storing `indexPath`s might be problematic when inserting rows etc... in this case it might be more useful to keep track of the checked objects *represented by* the cells.

Comment: @Jenox. Its working but when I scroll tableview, selected checkmarks goes disappear.

Comment: Then it does not work at all. Only -didSelectRowAtIndexPath: appears to work. Mind sharing a demo project with the issue with me?

Answer (score 0):

Since cells are being reused, you need to set the accessory mark to on or off for every cell in the table in the cellForRowAtInexPath table datasource method.

So the cell.accessoryType cell property should be soecified in the cellForRowAtInexPath and not the didSelectRow delegate method.

In the didSelectRow, just keep track of the selected rows in an array, and set the cells accessory mark to none or checkmark in the cellForRowAtInexPath dependingon the array value.

Comment: Your idea would work, but don't you think an `NSSet` is more useful than an `NSArray` in this case?

Comment: I don't know why the NSSet would give an advantage in this case, but yes it would also work great.

Comment: You use an `array` if the order of objects *does* matter, and a `set` if it does *not*. ;)

Comment: Interesting. I never used NSSet before. Will do some research. Thanks for pointing this out