# Swift: Multiple TableView checkmark - select all rows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, multi-select

It is posible to add a `select all` option in TableView Multiple checkmarks...?

I have a code ready, and I try to do this function. please help me !

**CODE:**

```
struct Area {
        let name : String
        var isSelected : Bool

        init(name : String, isSelected : Bool = false) {
            self.name = name
            self.isSelected = isSelected
        }
    }

    var areas = [Area(name: "Select all"),Area(name: "a"),Area(name: "b"),Area(name: "c"),Area(name: "d"]

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return areas.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let area = areas[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = area.name
        cell.accessoryType = area.isSelected ? .checkmark : .none

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        areas[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
        let selectedAreas = areas.filter{$0.isSelected}.map{$0.name}
        print(selectedAreas)

    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS: Tableview multiple selection - AccessoryCheckmark checking reusable cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216597/ios-tableview-multiple-selection-accessorycheckmark-checking-reusable-cells)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check if the user selected the first row ("Select all") and update the other rows accordingly:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // toggle the selected area
    areas[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()

    // save the new state for later use
    let isSelected = areas[indexPath.row].isSelected

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        // "Select all" was selected – update all areas
        for i in 1..<areas.count {
            areas[i].isSelected = isSelected
        }

        // update UI
        tableView.visibleCells.forEach { $0.accessoryType = isSelected ? .checkmark : .none }
    } else {
        // update UI
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
    }

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

**Recommendation**

To separate concerns visually you could also use an own table view section for the "Select all" row. In that case some more changes are necessary:

```
var areas = [
    // you do not need an area for "Select all" any longer
    Area(name: "a"),
    Area(name: "b"),
    Area(name: "c"),
    Area(name: "d")
]

var allSelected: Bool {
    // helper var to see if all areas are currently selected
    return areas.filter({!$0.isSelected}).isEmpty
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    switch section {
    case 1: return "Areas"
    default: return nil
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch section {
    case 0: return 1 // select all
    case 1: return areas.count
    default:
        // we should never get here
        fatalError()
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Select all"
        cell.accessoryType = allSelected ? .checkmark : .none
    } else {
        let area = areas[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = area.name
        cell.accessoryType = area.isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
    }

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        // (de-)select all
        let shouldSelect = !allSelected
        for i in 0..<areas.count {
            areas[i].isSelected = shouldSelect
        }
    } else {
        areas[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
    }

    tableView.reloadRows(at: tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows ?? [], with: .automatic)
}
```

Comment: perfect!!  Maybe you can help me if you know how to add a search option?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to enable multiple selection for the table view

```
tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
```

Select all rows

```
for section in 0..<tableView.numberOfSections {
        for row in 0..<tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section) {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
            tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
        }
    }
```

To enable checkmark whenever a row is selected:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        let area = areas[indexPath.row]
        area.isSelected = true
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }
}
```

Also remove checkmark when it is deselected:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        let area = areas[indexPath.row]
        area.isSelected = false
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    }
}
```

Please vote this answer if it helps. Thanks.

Comment: Works great!!  Maybe you can help me if you know how to add a search option? I will mark as the correct answer !!

Answer (score 0):

First change your Area to class so it will be reference type

```
    class Area {
        let name : String
        var isSelected : Bool

        init(name : String, isSelected : Bool = false) {
            self.name = name
            self.isSelected = isSelected
        }
    }
```

Now change your didselect logic

```
       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let area = areas[indexPath.row]
        area.isSelected.toggle()
        if area.name == "Select all"{
          areas = areas.map{$0.isSelected = true}
        }
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
        let selectedAreas = areas.filter{$0.isSelected}.map{$0.name}
        print(selectedAreas)

     }
```

Comment: Works great!!  Maybe do you know how to add a search option? I will mark as the correct answer !!

Comment: You don't need to change the struct to a reference type.

Comment: What you want to search?

Comment: Do you know how to add a search bar option?  To search for items in the list.

Comment: let arrSearchedResult = areas.filter{$0.name.contains("YOUR_SEARCH_TEXT")}

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/472-uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started link for  adding search bar tutorial

Answer (score 0):

In `didSelectRow`:

```
if indexPath.row == 0 { // the first item is the select all button
    // find out which areas should be selected
    let indicesThatShouldBeSelected = (1..<areas.count).filter { !areas[$0].isSelected }
    // update model
    indicesThatShouldBeSelected.forEach { areas[$0].isSelected = true }
    // update view
    tableView.reloadRows(at: indicesThatShouldBeSelected.map { IndexPath(section: 0, row: $0) }, with: .none)
}
```

You could also just do `tableView.reloadData()`, which reloads the whole table view instead of just the rows that needs reloading.

Comment: Works great!! Maybe do you know how to add a search option? I will mark as the correct answer !!

Answer (score 0):

If the `selectAll` row is at index 0 check the row, then set all `isSelected` members to `true` and reload the entire table

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        areas.indices.forEach{areas[$0].isSelected = true}
        tableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        areas[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
    }
    let selectedAreas = areas.filter{$0.isSelected}.map{$0.name}
    print(selectedAreas)

}
```

And if you want to exclude the first item to be selected drop the first index

```
areas.indices.dropFirst().forEach{areas[$0].isSelected = true}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!  Is it possible to view the selected items at the top of the list?

Comment: Yes, sort the items by `isSelected` and move `selectAll` to the top of the list

Comment: Can you please show me how to do it?  I will mark you as the correct answer !!

Comment: To sort items is very basic stuff.

Comment: Can you help me to add a search bar option please? That's the last thing I need

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57907282/how-to-put-a-checkmark-after-search/57909148#57909148. That's pretty similar to what you are going to accomplish.